# scale_x_discrete 5 ticks with 3 labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have 5 conditions:

```
 labels = c("Baseline","Passenger Drive","Passenger Drive","Remote Drive","Remote Drive")
```

and I would like to put a single label of "Passenger Drive" and "Remote Drive" halfway between the existing points.

Toy dataset:

```
  df <- data.frame(cbind(cbind(condition = c("Baseline","Passenger Drive",
                        "Passenger Drive","Remote Drive","Remote Drive"),
          rt_type = c("none",rep(c("driver_rt","other_rt"),2))),
  rt = c(.4,.6,.5,.7,.62)))

  ggplot(data = df,aes(x = interaction(rt_type,condition), y = rt)) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_line(group = 1, size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 3) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Baseline",
                              "Passenger Drive",
                              "Remote Drive")) +
  labs(x = "Condition by Speaker", y = "Reaction Time (s)",
       linetype = "Responder", shape = "Speaker")
```

[image: Interaction]

When I try scale_x_continous with breaks I get an error because the data is discrete and categorical. The actual dataset has several more variables represented so I'm not asking for a more efficient way to plot this data. I would just like to turn labels for 5 categorical x-axis positions into 3 x-axis labels. "Passenger Drive" would move between points 2 and 3 and "Remote Drive" would move between points 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create dummy numeric variable for the x axis and use `scale_x_continuous` instead of `scale_x_discrete`.

```
# This replaces interaction(rt_type, condition)
df$intr <- as.numeric(as.factor(interaction(df$rt_type, df$condition)))

# Creating dummy mid point to place labels in the middle
ref_avg <- aggregate(intr ~ condition, df, mean)
df$my_breaks <- ref_avg[match(df$condition, ref_avg$condition), "intr"]

ggplot(data = df,aes(x = intr, y = rt)) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_point(size = 3)  + 
  geom_path(group = 1) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = df$my_breaks, labels = df$condition) + 
  labs(x = "Condition by Speaker", y = "Reaction Time (s)",
       linetype = "Responder", shape = "Speaker")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In the end, it required a slightly more complex dummy code of 1 1 2 3 2 3 5 6 5 6 (due to the other variables), but it worked with scale_x_continuous.

Answer (score 1):

### Workaround

Simply change

```
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Baseline",
                              "Passenger Drive",
                              "Remote Drive")) +
```

to

```
  scale_x_discrete(labels = df$condition) +
```

### Desirable

I know you're not asking for a more efficient way but I think one variable(ex. rt_type) should be mapped to point shape.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = condition, y = rt, shape = rt_type)) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_point(size = 3,) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Baseline",
                              "Passenger Drive",
                              "Remote Drive")) +
  labs(
    x = "Condition by Speaker",
    y = "Reaction Time (s)"
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I mentioned efficiency because linetype and shape are already mapped to other variables as the plot is slightly more complex than the toy dataset.